# maxquant software on my HPDC does not seem to utilize the speed of my m.2 raid drives

Tags: windows-10, performance, raid, .net-framework, m.2

I am using a software called MaxQuant v. 1.6.6 to analyze proteiomic data. The computer in question has the following specs:

- gigabyte x299 motherboard
- i9-7980 chip (18 core, 36 logical, 2.6 GHz, runs
  around 4.4 GHz however)
- 64 GB RAM
- 2x Samsung m.2 1 TB drives set to RAID 0, this is used for processing the data only
- 1 Samsung SSD only used for OS and other software
- 1 12Tb standard 7200rpm drive for backup

MaxQuant is a stand-alone software package that runs out of its own folder. However, it utilizes the .NET Framework. My issue is that when I run the software on the RAID drive, I hardly see the speeds I would expect to see. It's almost as if something is limiting it's ability to reach full speed. Could this be a .NET issue? The .NET Framework is installed on the OS drive.

Using ATTO benchmark I have seen the RAID run at 2.9 Gb/s, but while the software is running I don't see over 200 Mb/s?

Comment: Thank you Worthwelle for the edits.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is 2.9Gb/s is the serial writing speed, but MaxQuant is never really write a huge chunk of data at once, instead it may write small piece of data periodically ,which may make average writing speed much slower than the serial writing speed.